# How do I make dynamic pages powered by WordPress Search filter pro SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, wordpress, url, search-engine-indexing, rel-canonical

I have a website which offers different services in different places.
So I have a search page that filters services and places.
I use wordpress CMS and Search filter pro plugin.

My urls are something like this:
`www.example.com/search/?_sft_category=ss&_sft_location=mm`
I wrote code to have different titles and meta description for each filter dynamically. I want these URLs to become indexed and rank in the first page of the Google search results.

The problem is that these pages didn't get indexed.  Even when I fetch these URLs using Google Search Console, it says they are excluded because of canonical tag to the search page.

How can I change it to allow Google to index the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, looks like you will have to address the canonical tag issue first. In your theme, try and see if you can change the page to avoid the canonical tag.

Also, re-think your approach for these location search pages. Perhaps by creating pages and embedding content you can get this with pretty urls as well?

Comment: I removed the canonical tag from that page. I don't know if google would index it now or not. we had thought about different pages for each location but it'd be difficult because the categories and locations are so many. I had seen websites who has their search pages having good positions on google pages.